# how to detect production environment in jquery mobile phonegap application?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, environment

I have a simple question. I have written a jquery mobile application that works fine and is deployed in production. I have some configuration values that change from my development environment to production environment. To detect whether I am running in development environment, I was using the following line of code (coffeescript)

```
env = if window.location.hostname.indexOf('localhost') == 0 then 'dev' else 'production'
```

This works fine. But when you start developing in phonegap environment, this is inadequate. For example, when running in ios 6 simulator, the window.location seems to be returning an empty string.

What is the right way of detecting a development environment in a jqm phonegap application that works in all situations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you use different bundle ids for dev and production apps. Then you can use the [wizUtils plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-wizUtils) and read the bundle identifier. And in a JS switch case statement, you can set dev and prod configurations depending on the bundle id. So this way you dont have to change anything in the source code when you do the prod build. if you are using the same bundle id for dev and prod, you will have to have a variable which will have the current environment value and this needs to be updated everytime you do a build for another environment.